# Brackets extension

Tags: php, adobe-brackets

I need help with brackets.

I was using sublime text 2 but i really like brackets but only problem is that sublime text 2 can highlight different programming language with different color.

For example if I type some html code it will be white but if I type php code background of that code is going to be different color for example blue!

Look at this picture:

[image]

Can I somehow make that in brackets? Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using a `.php` file you should be fine.

Example (Brackets v1.2):

[image]

Comment: This is without any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There is several extensions that will change the color of the the start tag of that coding language so if it goes from php to html to script there would be different colors for the    believe the extension is called ExtensionHighlighter. But installing adobes bracket themes will also do the same thing, try stoneage theme